# I'm unable to install typescript globally or any node packages on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, nodejs

I installed nodejs useing `sudo apt install nodejs`.
However everytime i wanted to install a package globally it required me to use `sudo` which is bad.
I followed these instructions so that i would be able to install packages globally without using `sudo` [Instructions followed](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)

But now when i run `npm install -g typescript` or any other package installation i get this log:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path /home/tony/.npm-global/lib
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/home/tony/.npm-global/lib'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/tony/.npm/_logs/2021-01-03T15_50_40_891Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who will stumble upon this in the future, i created a directory call `.npm-global/lib` and now i'm able to install packages.